# Return multiple values from map in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Let's say I have a map like this:

```
def map = [name: 'mrhaki', country: 'The Netherlands', blog: true, languages: ['Groovy', 'Java']]
```

Now I can return "submap" with only "name" and "blog" like this:

```
def keys = ['name', 'blog']
map.subMap(keys)
// Will return a map with entries name=mrhaki and blog=true
```

But is there a way to easily return multiple values instead of a list of entries?

Update:

I'd like to do something like this (which doesn't work):

```
def values = map.{'name','blog'}
```

which would yield for example `values` = `['mrhaki', true]` (a list or tuple or some other datastructure).

Comment: can you give us example? do you want the result to be ```['mrhaki', true]```?

Comment: But you might still want some way to specify which key, values to be retrieved, right?

Comment: That's a Map, not a list of Entries...

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: @Johan check my answer, if you are looking for shorter answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate over the submap and collect the values:

```
def values = map.subMap(keys).collect {it.value}
// Result: [mrhaki, true]
```

Or, iterate over the list of keys, returning the map value for that key:

```
def values = keys.collect {map[it]}
```

I would guess the latter is more efficient, not having to create the submap.

A more long-winded way to iterate over the map

```
def values = map.inject([]) {values, key, value -> 
    if (keys.contains(key)) {values << value}
    values
}
```

Comment: So there's no "special syntax" for extracting multiple values from a map like I'm proposing with my fictive example?

Comment: I don't think so. Pretty sure you need to pick one of the iterator methods.

Answer (score 6):

```
map.subMap(keys)*.value
```

> The Spread Operator (*.) is used to invoke an action on all items of
>   an aggregate object. It is equivalent to calling the action on each
>   item and collecting the result into a list

Comment: Very nice. Here's the documentation: http://www.groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_spread_operator

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I'll add another way of accomplishing this using [Map.findResults](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#findResults(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
map.findResults { k, v -> k in keys ? v : null }
```

flexible, but more long-winded than some of the previous answers.